# Help me improve my workout routine; I feel some muscle groups aren't getting enough attention

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, muscle-gain

**About myself:**

29m, 5'2", 142lbs. Been doing some home workouts as well as running around the neighborhood, but decided it wasn't good enough so I've been going to gym for the past 4 months. Average build, but definitely could lose some roundness around belly.

**Workout routine each week:**

*Every routine starts with 5 min of warm-up and ends with 28 min of run/walk cycle on the treadmill

**Mon (Chest & Triceps w/ some abs):**

- Bench Press, 8 reps 4 sets
- Incline dumbbell press, 10 reps 4 sets
- Tricep pushdown, 10 reps 4 sets
- Dumbbell Chest flyes, 12 reps 4 sets
- Skull crushers, 12 reps 4 sets
- Abs rollout, 12 reps 3 sets
- Side-to-side abs rollout 12 reps 3 sets

**Tues (Back & Biceps w/ some abs):**

- Cable rows, 10 reps 3 sets
- Lat pulldowns, 10 reps 3 sets
- Bent-over rows with barbells, 12 reps 3 sets
- Dumbbell bicep curls, 12 reps 3 sets
- Deadlift, 10 reps 3 sets
- Barbell bicep curls, 10 reps 3 sets
- Straight arm pulldown, 10 reps 3 sets
- Concentration curls, 12 reps 3 sets
- Abs rollout, 12 reps 3 sets
- Side-to-side abs rollout 12 reps 3 sets

**Wed (Core & abs):**

- Crunches, 15 reps 3 sets
- Hanging leg raises 12 reps 3 sets
- Abs rollout 12 reps 3 sets
- Side-to-side abs rollout 12 reps 3 sets
- Dumbbell side obliques, 12 reps 3 sets
- Plank, 30 sec 3 sets
- Side planks, 30 sec each side, 3 sets
- Heel touches 12 reps 3 sets
- Vertical leg crunch, 12 reps 3 sets

**Thurs (Shoulder & Triceps):**

- Shoulder press, 10 reps 4 sets
- Military Press, 10 reps 4 sets
- Dips, 10 reps 4 sets
- Side lat raise, 12 reps 4 sets
- Tricep extension, 12 reps 4 sets
- Frontal lat raise, 10 reps 4 sets
- Tricep pushdown, 12 reps 4 sets
- Reverse flyes, 12 reps 4 sets
- Shoulder shrugs, 10 reps 4 sets

**Fri (Legs & Biceps):**

- Weighted squats, 10 reps 4 sets
- barbell bicep curls, 12 reps 4 sets
- Leg press, 10 reps 4 sets
- Leg curls, 10 reps 4 sets
- Calf raises, 12 reps 4 sets
- Lying leg curls, 12 reps 4 sets
- Dumbbell bicep curls, 12 reps 4 sets
- Leg extensions, 12 reps 4 sets

**Sat & Sun:**

- Rest days

**Diet & Lifestyle:**

I do intermediate fasting, where I don't eat from 8 pm the previous night to 12 pm the next day. When I'm "allowed to eat", I eat a lot of rice (I come from a Korean household), but I always make sure to take a small portion of rice and eat more of side dishes consisting of veggies and protein. Always make sure to get at least 1 serving of fruits each day.
Currently working as a remote Data Analyst, I find myself sitting down for the majority of the day. I tried to get up and walk around the house a lot, or take my dog out for a walk. I drink water frequently, around 6-7 cups a day, not counting the water I chug down during workouts.
When it comes to sleep, I always make sure to get 7-8 hours of sleep each night.

**What I'm hoping:**

The triceps and biceps are being worked out pretty regularly, but Chest, Back, Shoulders, and Legs only get worked out once a week. I'm looking to balance out the routine to work out all groups regularly, to have all groups worked out at least twice a week

Answer (score -1):

The actual exercises you are doing are fairly good but if you're trying to increasebthe amount of workouts here's the routine I use.

Day 1: cheat, shoulders, triceps
Day 2: back, biceps
Day 3: legs, abs
Day 4: rest
Repeat

I use this and I feel like I get plenty of volume but still enough rest and recovery.